# HDMI to DVI audio problem

Tags: lcd, hdmi, dvi, speakers

I have a Samsung T220HD LCD with integrated speakers. When I connect it to my video card via VGA cable, the speakers works fine. But, I recently bought an DVI to HDMI cable, (my video card has dvi outputs too). When I connect the HDMI to DVI cable, the speakers don't work. I used to connect my monitor speakers to the audio card via one jack cable. But I repeat, this works only on VGA. I tried also an jack wich finishes in two analog cables. I connected the jack to my sound card, and the analog inputs (Left and Right) to my monitor audio-in. Still no sound.

So, is there a solution to make my monitor speakers work on a DVI to HDMI connection? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you connect the audio cable to the 'HDMI/PC/DVI-D AUDIO IN' port on the back of the TV using the weird Red/White to Single Blue connector your TV/Monitor may have come with.

Why don't you just use a DVI cable instead of a DVI to HDMI converter cable? Your TV supports DVI, and HDMI cables have the capability to contain audio, so the TV might trying to get non-existent audio out of the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly be a software problem.

As DVI and HDMI are electrically compatible, and HDMI can have audio, your pc may be redirecting it incorrectly.

I personally have not seen this with a card that is just DVI, but it may be worth checking your sound driver's program / manager and Windows audio manager (if using windows) and just make sure that audio is being directed out the correct port.

For my laptop, the moment I plug in a HDMI cable, my local audio just mutes unless I set the internal speakers to default.

Answer (score 1):

especially if you have a recent ATI gfx card (>HD3000) the chip got it's own audio device to be able to provide audio (you should see a 2nd audio device). This integrated only works with the DVI to HDMI adapter provided with the card since it seems to include some logic. Standard DVI to HDMI cables don't support audio.
As said above: Either make sure you use the standard audio or use the ATI dongle and the integrated audio in this (ATI) case.